# price textbox double

Tags: c#

I wondering of anyone can help. I have a homework and a questien in it i dont understand what i need to look for to figuer out how to find it.

This is what i need to look for

Convert the contents of the price TextBox to a double and
validate the converted value so it is >= 0.0.
Call the GetDouble method from the InputUtility class,
with min value 0 and max value some big number.
Use a const declaration for the max.value

this is what im going to get in to my if before im going to tell its true

can enter the code two

```
private bool ReadAndValidatePrice(out double price)
{
    if
    {
        price = txtPrice.Text;
        return true;
    }
   else
    {
   MessageBox.Show("Enter Numbers Only", "Invalid Character", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtPrice.Focus();
        return false;
```

What i fink im going to do is if it is 0.0 or bigger it going to type it out. im i going to do like 0.0 > 999999

Comment: What code did you already tried to make yourself (even if it doesn't work or compile)?

Comment: Sidebar: tell your instructor to update the requirement to use `System.Decimal` (alias `decimal`) when dealing with financial data.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best I can do with the little information you are presenting. You don't have to declare a double and save the converted data to it, but it makes it easier to read.

```
        double converted;
        converted = Convert.ToDouble(priceTB.text)
        // Check if the converted data and if is less than 0, return out of the method    
        if(converted >= 0.0)
                return;
```